# Using List as a key in map in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

Here is my Dart code

```
var mp = new Map();
  mp[[1,2]] = "Hi";
  mp[[3,5]] = "sir";
  mp.remove([3,5]);
  print(mp);
```

**Output here is null**

How can i access value at mp[[3,5]]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two list instances containing the same elements is not equal to each other in Dart. This is the reason your example does not work.

If you want to create a `Map` which works like your example, you can use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.0/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap/LinkedHashMap.html) from `dart:collection` (basically the same when you are using `Map()`) to create an instance with its own definition of what it means for keys to be equal and how `hashCode` is calculated for a key.

So something like this if you want to have keys to be equal if the list contains the same elements in the same order. It should be noted it does not support nested lists:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final mp = LinkedHashMap<List<int>, String>(
    equals: (list1, list2) {
      if (list1.length != list2.length) {
        return false;
      }
      
      for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        if (list1[i] != list2[i]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      
      return true;
    },
    hashCode: Object.hashAll,
  );

  mp[[1, 2]] = "Hi";
  mp[[3, 5]] = "sir";
  mp.remove([3, 5]);
  print(mp); // {[1, 2]: Hi}
}
```

I should also add that this is really an inefficient way to do use maps and I am highly recommend to never use `List` as keys in maps.

Answer (score 0):

You add a list instance as a key to the Map object. You need the corresponding list instance to delete it again.

There are two ways to access

First;

```dart
  final mp = {};
  mp[[1,2]] = "Hi";
  mp[[3,5]] = "sir";
  mp.removeWhere((key, value) {
    if(key is List){
      return key.first == 3 && key[1] == 5;
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Second;

```dart
  final mp = {};
  final key = [3, 5];
  mp[[1,2]] = "Hi";
  mp[key] = "sir";
  mp.remove(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map countries = {

"01": "USA",

"02": "United Kingdom",

"03": "China",

"04": "India",

"05": "Brazil",

"06": "Nepal",

"07": "Russia"

};

**//method 1:**

```
var _key = countries.keys.firstWhere((k)
      => countries[k] == 'Russia', orElse: () => null);
```

print(key); //output: 07